# php mail() is not sending emails

Tags: email, php

I am using php mail to notify my subscribers of new blog posts.
Because my below function wasn't sending I decided to add an error catcher, and mail() returns true, and it shows my email address, however the email is not sent. Please help

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subscribers";
    while ($ste = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql)))
    {
    $messager="
<html>
<head>
<title>Check out what's happening on my Blog this week</title>
<body>
";  
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date("H"),date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d")-7));
    $sqli = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE date > '$date' LIMIT 2";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
    while ($jw = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $messager = $messager."<h2>$jw[header] by $jw[author]</h2><p>".substr($jw["text"], 0, 250)."..."."</p><br>";
    }
    $messager = $messager."</body></html>";
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <no-reply@zinteen.co.uk>';
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion(); 
   $ma= mail("$ste[email]", "Check out what's happening on my Blog this week",
    $messager, $headers);
    if ($ma)
    die("should've worked.".$ste["email"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your spam folder? How about the mail server error logs? If `mail()` is returning true, then the email is being passed to the mail server successfully, so the problem lies somewhere between there and the recipient.

Comment: my spam folder is empty

Comment: Have you signed up for your own email? If you have, then you'll have to have a look at the mailserver logs.

Comment: @andrewsi i am on free hosting

Comment: The only real option then would be to try and speak to the postmaster at your hosting provider, and see if they can tell you anything. But it's possible that your emails are being flagged as spam somewhere along the way.

Comment: If it were me I would just try a very simplified example.  Write a very simple script like `mail("me@myaddress.com", "Test Subject", "Are you receiving?");`   My suspiscion is that your free hosting has outbound mail disabled or charges a fee for that service.  If you don't receive your simple test, contact support and inquire.

Comment: I would use SMTP, and not PHP's built in mail() unless you have access to the `php.ini` and can see how it is configured.

Comment: @user2751288 You need an opening brace after `if ($ma)` such as `if ($ma) {` for one thing. Your code is presently broken.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - not necessarily. The closing brace on the following line looks like it matches the one on the `while` at the top (though that does leave the final brace hanging.) This is why consistent indentation is useful.

Comment: @andrewsi Not from within Notepad++ it doesn't ;-) (mismatched) however I can see what you mean though. I hate having loose ends.

Answer (score 0):

Contact with server administator, or try to use SMTP with providing auth credentials

Very usefull mail class for php

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: hello i have tried this but it returns `SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.!!`

Comment: do u have provided login, password, smtp server name, and smtp server port? it may not configured by default on server, so u can register an mail address on gmail and use it's params

Answer (score 0):

You should position your quotes another way:

```
$ma= mail($ste["email"], "Check out what's happening on my Blog this week",
$messager, $headers);
```

I changed them at your email.